# Signed and unsigned instructions for MASM

Tags: assembly, masm

How do you know if instructions are signed or unsigned in MASM x86 assembly language?

Comment: The x86 instruction set reference has the instructions, the masm manual has the directives and stuff. Note that asking for resources is off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I think I've found what I need.

Comment: add and subtraction have no signage, multiply and divide do, read the instruction set docs.  there are signed and unsigned flags.

Answer (score 3):

For division, multiplication and right shift; there are different instructions for signed data (`imul`, `idiv`, `sar`) and unsigned data (`mul`, `div`, `shr`).

For conditional branches, there are different instructions for signed (`jo`, `jl`, `jnl`, `jg`, `jng`, `js`, `jns`) and unsigned  (`jc`, `jb`, `jnb`, `ja`, `jna`) which check different flags.

For addition, subtraction (including `cmp`) and bitwise instructions (`and`, `or`, `xor`, etc; including `test`) it makes no difference if it's signed or unsigned so the same instructions work the same for either case. The difference is which flags you care about later (if any), not the instruction itself.

For example, you might do `sub eax,123` (regardless of whether the value in `eax` is signed or unsigned), and then have a `jo .tooBig` (if the result of the subtraction was signed) or `jc .tooBig` (if the result of the subtraction was unsigned) to determine if the subtraction overflowed.

Note: For left shifts, the instruction `shl` works the same for both signed and unsigned; but assemblers can allow the alternative name `sal` for the same thing (different name, same opcode, same machine code) to make it seem similar to right shifts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is very helpful for me.